# See SFINAE reason for a certain function

Tags: c++, clang, sfinae

I'm using CLang. Is there a way for a certain function or whole `.cpp` to treat [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) as error? If there is an option `--sfinae-as-error`, or `#pragma sfinae_disable`/`#pragma sfinae_enable` for a certain function?

It seems that due to SFINAE my function specialization has disappeared (became unusable) and I don't know how to find the reason why it has failed (where SFINAE comes from), basically I have unintentional SFINAE case and I want to find out the line that causes it.

To explain this, I have a small method:

```
template <typename To>
auto casttc() const {
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<To, T>)
        return *this;
    Vec<RTBits, Bits, To> c;
    auto constexpr castt_ = castt_reg_helper<RTGet<To>, RT>::f;
    LOOPM({ GI; c.template reg<I>() = castt_(this->template reg<I>()); });
    return c;
}
```

From another method I call it like `this->template casttc<u64>()` and it gives compile error:

```
drafts/intrin_simd3.hpp:199:10: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with To = unsigned long long]
    auto casttc() const {
```

Line 199 in above error message points to `auto casttc() const {`.

There were several screens of error log and these lines are last lines of this log:

```
In file included from drafts/cordic.cpp:12:
In file included from drafts/intrin_simd3.hpp:157:
drafts/intrin_simd2.hpp:140:61: error: no matching member function for call to 'casttc'
        *this = this->template casttc<T0>().and_(b.template casttc<T0>()).template casttc<T>();
                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
drafts/intrin_simd3.hpp:199:10: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with To = unsigned long long]
    auto casttc() const {
```

So basically it says that for some reason `<u64>` specialization of this function can't be used. And I don't know in advance what is causing this problem.

Some time later I managed to find out the problem, which was that `castt_reg_helper<RTGet<To>, RT>` has no specialization for given template arguments. After I added necessary specialization everything started to compile.

So I'm concerned that CLang didn't give me precise reason of error, it just said that `<u64>` specialization is unusable without extra reasons. As I understand this specialization was removed (or became unusable) due to SFINAE. So for similar cases I want to be able to see precise reason of failure without compiler silently using SFINAE.

In my case function was not very big and I was able to find error manually. But if the body of a function is huge (I had such case before), finding reason of SFINAE could be problematic and takes a lot of time.

Comment: One way might be to comment out all the overloads except one.  That way you should get a more informative error message.

Comment: SFINAE depends of signature, not body of the function...

Comment: @PaulSanders I don't have overloads, I have just this function that I showed.

Comment: @Jarod42 Please see text of my function. When I implemented `castt_reg_helper` specialization for necessary types then error disappeared. It means for some reason, maybe not SFINAE, but CLang didn't say that error was due to `castt_reg_helper` not being specialized for given types.

Comment: @Jarod42 Basically CLang didn't say anything about body of `casttc()` at all. It just said about header of function `note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with To = unsigned long long]`.

Comment: Error seems short too. generally we have more context, Isn't the error point that subsitution fails for `castt_reg_helper<RTGet<To>, RT>::f` in `casttc<long long>`?

Comment: @Jarod42 No, line 199 points to `auto casttc() const {`

Comment: please include the complete error message. Is that really all?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It had one extra error line of the place where this `casttc` was called from. I just included that whole error in my question's post.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Basically there was many errors, several screens. Thanks for pointing out, my errors that I provided were at the very end of log, and several screens above in the beginning of log I found this `drafts/intrin_simd3.hpp:203:33: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'asimd::Vec<256, 512, double>::castt_reg_helper<__attribute__((__vector_size__(4 * sizeof(long long)))) long long, __attribute__((__vector_size__(4 * sizeof(double)))) double>'

        auto constexpr castt_ = castt_reg_helper<RTGet<To>, RT>::f;` . Which solves my question. Sorry for disturb.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question doesn't capture enough detail to be searchable, and the circumstances are unlikely to be seen by others. If this question were salvageable at all, I'd first suggest rewriting the question to be shorter and mention the actual problem that is build-environment related. At first hunch, I'd classify the OP's problem as "needs to be slept over", i.e. something easily found out on a fresh mind. Been there, done that, I admit :)

Comment: @Arty "Sorry for disturb": 1. Answers *never* belong in the question. 2. The way to "apologize" for a question is to close it yourself. Actions count more than words :)

Comment: Besides: What sort of a build environment do you use? No reasonable IDE should behave that way, and yes, you can run CI builds under IDE control, with proper marking of errors in the sources etc. - check it out :)

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica When I clicked to close a question there were several reasons to close. Among them was no reason that I wanted like `question due to mistake`.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I had a special build system written for our Organization. It is not any well-known open-source system. Basically this system just truncates error messages to show only last screen on console. Of cause it shows in the beginning that some lines were truncated but I didn't notice this by mistake. If one wants to see all errors then one should look into log file.

Comment: @Arty You can close your own question for any reason: you just delete it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically my build system just outputted last screen of errors, it truncated errors to last screen showing on console. Of cause in the beginning of screen it showed tiny message that truncation happened but I didn't noticed that. And when I restored whole log there appeared following lines:

```
In file included from drafts/cordic.cpp:12:
drafts/intrin_simd3.hpp:203:33: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'asimd::Vec<256, 512, double>::castt_reg_helper<__attribute__((__vector_size__(4 * sizeof(long long)))) long long, __attribute__((__vector_size__(4 * sizeof(double)))) double>'
        auto constexpr castt_ = castt_reg_helper<RTGet<To>, RT>::f;
                                ^
```

which solve my problem. Apparently it appeared that it wasn't SFINAE reason and that CLang actually showed detailed reason but far above in the error log.

So my question was a mistake not due to bad CLang but due to me not noticing that my build system truncated errors.

We have a special build system written specifically for our organization and our needs. It is not any well known open source build system.